# Validation against current user in Pydantic model using FastAPI

Tags: validation, fastapi, pydantic

I have a question and I'm much surprised that nobody asked it before.
The question is: how to make validation against logged in user in Pydantic BaseModel? This is very easy in Django, where we can pass the request object to serializer, but I have no idea how to make it here.

My view:

```py
@router.post("/train_models", summary="Train models", response_model=SuccessResponse)
def train_models(train: TrainModels, user: TokenData = Depends(get_current_user),):
    # do some work here
    return {'success': True}
```

My BaseModel:

```py
class TrainModels(BaseModel):
    target_column: str
    user_file_id: int

    @root_validator()
    def validate(cls, values):
        return values
```

I want to be sure that the user has access to `user_file_id`, that this is his item and he has access to it, but how?
I think I can do this check inside my view, but I want to see my code clear and all validation logic to be kept strictly inside validators.

Maybe there is some way to pass some args to `root_validator` and do checks in there.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that business logic doesn't belong in your pydantic model (and the model shouldn't go around fetching data from the database, etc.), but should be the responsibility of the service storing or retrieving the actual objects.

One option is to let your service throw an error when saving:

```py
class TrainModelsService:
    def save_train_model(train: TrainModels, user: User):
        user_file = self.user_file_service.get_for_user_id(train.user_file_id, user.id)

        if not user_file:
            raise InvalidUserFile

        self.db_session.....


@router.post("/train_models", summary="Train models", response_model=SuccessResponse)
def train_models(train: TrainModels, 
                 user: TokenData = Depends(get_current_user),
                 train_service: TrainService = Depends(get_train_service)
):
    try:
        train_service.save_train_model(train)
    except InvalidUserFile:
        # or use an exception handler that does this for you instead of having it in your view.
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid user file")
    # do some work here
    return {'success': True}
```

Another option is to use the Depends hierarchy as you do for your user:

```py
def get_valid_train_model_for_user(train: TrainModels, 
                                   user: TokenData = Depends(get_current_user),
                                   user_file_service: UserFileService = Depends(get_user_file_service),
                          ):
    user_file = user_file_service.get_for_user_id(train.user_file_id, user.id)

    if not user_file:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Invalid user file given')

    return train


@router.post("/train_models", summary="Train models", response_model=SuccessResponse)
def train_models(train: TrainModels = Depends(get_valid_train_model_for_user)):
    # do some work here
    return {'success': True}
```

I tend to prefer using the Dependency hierarchy as much as possible to enforce constraints, as it makes it very easy to compose dependencies and reuse these dependencies in different ways across views.